# Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this problem in react native version 0.68.2

```
Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this package because the picker was removed from react native:
https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker

Install it using

```
npm install @react-native-picker/picker --save
```

OR

```
yarn add @react-native-picker/picker
```

You can then import the Picker Element like this:

```
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try installing  @react-native-picker/picker instead of just "Picker"

try this command :
npm install @react-native-picker/picker --save

You can read more about it here - https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker